# Android: MarginLayoutParams not working well on all phones

Tags: android, margin, layoutparams

I have a fullscreen view which I partially move in and out from the phone screen, let's say to the half of the screen.

To do this I am using MarginLayoutParameters to set the top margin to half of the screen, or to 0 in case I want it to be fully visible.

Everything works perfect but now that I am testing on other phones, which seem to be the ones of low resolution, the view is correctly cut by half but is always aligned to the top.

Trying left and right margins also always aligns it to the left.

Am I missing something that newer phones/ Android OS already does for me?.

This view is inside a FrameLayout.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just used setPadding with the same results I wanted to achieve, but my question still remains.